# where the serializer in perform_createt comes from?

Tags: django-rest-framework

Although serializer as parameter passed in perform_create method, it is not clear where it pass from. Can anyone explain where the serializer parameter pass from and how it works?

```
 class SnippetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the `CreateModelMixin`:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```